# how to create 15% lighter color dynamically in php

Tags: php, dynamic, colors, hex

for example i have an hexadecimal color code like #00ff00

i want to create or find the 15% lighter color code using php or javascript or jQuery ..

any small to best solutions are welcome.

thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find two methods, converting HTML hexa colorcode to decimal and back.

[Converter methods](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_convert_rgb_from_to_html_hex_color.xml)

Using these you can parse the hexadecimal color code to three decimal number numbers. After this you could do you transformation. I am not a color expert, but you could just make them 15% percent more intense. I am not sure that this is you intention, but you could do it like this:

```
function html2rgb($color)
{
    if ($color[0] == '#')
        $color = substr($color, 1);

    if (strlen($color) == 6)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[1],
                                 $color[2].$color[3],
                                 $color[4].$color[5]);
    elseif (strlen($color) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[0], $color[1].$color[1], $color[2].$color[2]);
    else
        return false;

    $r = hexdec($r); $g = hexdec($g); $b = hexdec($b);

    return array($r, $g, $b);
}

function rgb2html($r, $g=-1, $b=-1)
{
    if (is_array($r) && sizeof($r) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = $r;

    $r = intval($r); $g = intval($g);
    $b = intval($b);

    $r = dechex($r<0?0:($r>255?255:$r));
    $g = dechex($g<0?0:($g>255?255:$g));
    $b = dechex($b<0?0:($b>255?255:$b));

    $color = (strlen($r) < 2?'0':'').$r;
    $color .= (strlen($g) < 2?'0':'').$g;
    $color .= (strlen($b) < 2?'0':'').$b;
    return '#'.$color;
}

$hexa = "#CCDDEE";
$rgb = html2rgb($hexa)

// Do the transformation you would like to do
$rgb[0] *=1.15;
$rgb[2] *=1.15;
$rgb[3] *=1.15;

$hexa = rgb2html($rgb);
```

I didn't test this solution. It is just an idea how you could go.

Maybe it would be even easier to use CSS. CSS support rgb colors, like:

```
p
{
    background-color:rgb(255,0,255);
}
```

This way you could save all the effort of converting and avoid the possible problems of these conversions.